# How to validate date format yyyymmddsssss using python regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, datetime

I tried different regular expressions to match yyyymmddsssss but nothing is working. Could you let me know how to match "yyyymmddsssss" format in python regular expressions?

```
Ex: 2017122512345

2017 - year
12 - month
25 - day of month
12345 - milliseconds
```

Comment: What do you mean "validate"? `\d{13}` would match the pattern, but if you want to be sure it's a date *try parsing it as a date*.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean microseconds?  And 6 digits instead of 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Why go the regular expression route for this kind of a problem?](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/208:_Regular_Expressions)

[image]

[Easier to ask for forgiveness](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) - try loading with `datetime.strptime()` and handle a possible `ValueError` - `%Y%m%d%f` format should be what you are looking for:

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: def validate(date_string):
            try:
                datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y%m%d%f')
                print('Valid')
            except ValueError:
                print('Invalid')


In [3]: validate('2017122512345')
Valid

In [4]: validate('20171')
Invalid

In [5]: validate('illegal')
Invalid
```